curl: (28) Failed to connect to api.ipify.org port 443 after 134767 ms: Connection timed out
I'm trying to get public ip via api.ipify.org but failed in curl connection time out.
This is my iptables:
❯ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

This is my ufw:
❯ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

❯ nslookup ipify.org
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ipify.org
Address: 175.139.142.25

❯ nslookup ipify.org 1.1.1.1
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ipify.org
Address: 104.26.13.205
Name:   ipify.org
Address: 172.67.74.152
Name:   ipify.org
Address: 104.26.12.205

At first, I can't ping ipify
❯ ping ipify.org
PING ipify.org (175.139.142.25) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- ipify.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3057ms

After I added 172.67.14.152 ipify.org into the /etc/hosts, I can ping ipify.org but still cannot curl properly.
❯ ping ipify.org
PING ipify.org (172.67.74.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ipify.org (172.67.74.152): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=12.2 ms
64 bytes from ipify.org (172.67.74.152): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=6.88 ms
64 bytes from ipify.org (172.67.74.152): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=8.72 ms
64 bytes from ipify.org (172.67.74.152): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=8.64 ms
64 bytes from ipify.org (172.67.74.152): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=8.18 ms
^C
--- ipify.org ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.881/8.917/12.157/1.748 ms
❯ curl https://api.ipify.org
^C
❯ curl https://api.ipify.org
curl: (28) Failed to connect to api.ipify.org port 443 after 134744 ms: Connection timed out


temporary Solution: Added below lines into /etc/hosts
172.67.74.152   ipify.org
172.67.74.152   api.ipify.org

But I'm still wonder why the nslookup without 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 will be showing wrong ip address for ipify.org.
